# Falling leaves and black spots on bonsai tree. What can I do to return it to health?

Tags: bonsai

I bought this bonsai last week. There was no info on what breed it is? What can I do past watering?

[image: bonsai black spots]

[image: bonsai]

Comment: If it is deciduous, that might be natural leaf drop

Comment: I think it might be an azalea of some sort, but I'm interested in the area to the left (in the top pic) on the trunk, just above lower leaves - it appears to be covered in white deposit or fuzz, along with more fuzz on the top of the soil on the left. Is that the case, or is it just a trick of the light in the photo?

Comment: That'll be the light!

Answer (score 1):

One of the leave shapes look like a fukien tea, but the rest don't.  Looks deciduous, tropical.  The black is hard to tell from the pictures, looks like dirt.  lol But probably mold or fungus.